# Getting access to the user's google sheet with OAUTH

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-sheets, oauth, google-sheets-api

I hope you know about diagrams.net. This website allows the user to login with his/her gmail, and it asks for permission to access of the user's google drive.  After that it can freely do CRUD on the google-drive

I want the same but with only google sheets not the whole google-drive

How to implement this feature?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately its not that simple.

If you want access to a users google sheet.  Then you need access to their drive account.  There is now way to get access to only the sheets.  Its all or nothing.

If you just want to read a single sheet you still need the read only drive scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

Which gives you access to `See and download all your Google Drive files`

If you want to write to the file using the google sheets api. then you are going to need

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Which gives you access `See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files`

again this is all or nothing. There is no way to limit it to a single file or file mimetype.